# why does the first portion of code keep repeating?

Tags: python, function, python-import

```
import sys
```

I cant check if this import works because the code itself doesn't work

```
options_list = [1,2,3]

def options(options_list):
    print ("\n1. Hypotenuse solver \n2. Scat jazz \n3. Exit")
    print ("Enter the number of the option you would like")
    option = input()
    return option

option = options(options_list)

while option not in options_list:
    option = options(options_list)

if option in options_list:
    if option == 1:
        print ("...")
```

I'll add this later, hopefully

```
    elif option == 2:
        print ("Scoobidibahbahbah")
    elif option == 3:
        sys.exit
```

this is for a school project, a hypotenuse solver with a menu

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Pasting your code into my editor results in the following warnings: _Shadows name 'options_list' from outer scope_, 
_Parameter 'options_list' value is not used_.

Comment: Presumably you wrote it that way. What is your problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting option to int before returning it from options method.

Instead of `return option`, try `return int(option)`

input() reads values as string. When you are comparing `option==1`, a string and integer are compared and there are no else statements which handles this scenario. Also the option that you have got is always not in `options_list`. That is why your code keeps on going on an infinite loop without printing anything.

The `import` works correctly because `sys` is a reliable python package.